# Https Certbot Certificate is renewed, but connection not secure till you restart nginx

Tags: nginx, certbot

My domain was showing as not secure on google chrome.

I logged as root to my server ran this command:

```
certbot certificates
```

It produced this output: The certbot cerificate was valid.

```
Found the following certificates:
Certificate Name: xyz.com
Domains: xyz.com www.xyz.com
Expiry date: 2022-01-14 (valid: 58 days)
Certificate path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/xyz.com/fullchain.pem
Private key path: ....
```

However, the website was showing as NOT secure.

After this I ran :

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Then the website became secure.

**What can I do so that I do not need to restart nginx everytime the certificate renews?**

I am using Nginx 1.14.0 on ubuntu 18.04.5
The version of my client is : certbot 0.31.0

Answer (score 19):

You do not need to restart Nginx, but you do need to tell Nginx that the certificate has changed so that it can reload it. Using `nginx -s reload` (and probably `sudo systemctl reload nginx` would work too).

This can be combined with the `certbot` renewal command, for example:

```
certbot renew --post-hook "nginx -s reload"
```

Comment: This does not work for me, I still have to run `nginx -s reload` manually after `renew` is ran